# Nginx redirect for specific file extension

Tags: nginx, rewrite, magento

I'm having trouble setting up the redirects for a Magento extension. The URL requested is:

```
example.com/index.php/Cdiscount/Package/download/type/offers/filename/BMS_PREFIX_161d529d7c3ef4b5ae1dca92e2334de6/BMS_PREFIX_161d529d7c3ef4b5ae1dca92e2334de6.zip
```

but nginx should return:

```
example.com/index.php/Cdiscount/Package/download/type/offers/filename/BMS_PREFIX_161d529d7c3ef4b5ae1dca92e2334de6
```

instead.

The part between `BMS_PREFIX_` and `.zip` will often change, so this should probably fetch all .zip file requests in the offers/ location. I am not 100% sure if the *filename* in `offers/filename/BMS_PREFIX...` is configurable to be something else or changes per request, but I assume that it won't change.

So basically I need to tell Nginx to reply with `example.com/path/` when a request for `example.com/path/path.zip` is requested.

current config:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6081;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    #proxy_hide_header X-Varnish;
    proxy_hide_header Via;
    proxy_hide_header Vary;
    proxy_hide_header X-Server;
    proxy_hide_header X-Backend-Server;
    proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_connect_timeout      7200;
    proxy_send_timeout         7200;
    proxy_read_timeout         7200;
    proxy_buffer_size          256k;
    proxy_buffers              4 512k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    512k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 512k;
}
```

Comment: Could you add the Nginx configuration file?

Comment: done :) let me know if that is enough or if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean something like this

```
rewrite ^(/index\.php/Cdiscount/Package/download/type/offers/filename/BMS_PREFIX_)(.+?)/BMS_PREFIX_(.+).zip $1$2;
```

Add above line before `proxy_pass` statement.

**Notes**:

- To check the rewrite is working, either setup request logging at Magento or you can use [rewrite_log](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite_log)  by nginx
- This rewrite doesn't check whether **BMS_PREFIX after filename** and **BMS_PREFIX before .zip** is same string. In other words, request `example.com/path/otherpath.zip` will still rewritten to to `example.com/path`
- For explanation of that regex scheme, see [here](http://regex101.com/r/eQ0fL4/1).